# Optimizing or tweaking the following implementation for Merge Sort 3 way

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have recently been playing with sorting algorithms, and upon touching the Merge Sort algorithm, I wanted to try and implement the algorithm's merge helper function using 3 sorted lists, as opposed to 2. 
 My current implementation works, but I was wondering if there is perhaps some way to tweak it or implement in differently to make it run faster.

Here is the code:

```
def merge_three(l1, l2, l3):
    """This function returns a sorted list made out of the three
    given lists.

    >>> merge_three([9, 29], [1, 7, 15], [8, 17, 21])
    [1, 7, 8, 9, 15, 17, 21, 29]
    """

    index1, index2, index3 = 0, 0, 0
    to_loop = len(l1) + len(l2) + len(l3)
    sorted_list = []

    i = 0
    while i < to_loop:
        advance = 0
        value = float("inf")

        if index1 < len(l1) and l1[index1] <= value:
            advance = 1
            value = l1[index1]

        if index2 < len(l2) and l2[index2] <= value:
            advance = 2
            value = l2[index2]

        if index3 < len(l3) and l3[index3] <= value:
            advance = 3
            value = l3[index3]

        sorted_list.append(value)

        if advance == 1:
            index1 += 1
        elif advance == 2:
            index2 += 1
        else:
            index3 += 1

        i += 1
    return sorted_list
```

Thank you :)

Comment: If you have working code and are looking for improvements, a better place to post would be: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Fastest way would probably be something like `return sorted(l1 + l2 + l3)`.

Comment: Actual Python code is about 50 times as slow as compiled code in other languages, so it's best to use library functions as much as possible, since they are compiled code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about a more general merge function leads to a simpler design.  Suppose you wanted to write a function that takes a list of sorted lists and merges all the lists.  The idea is simple: find the list with the smallest element, pop it off, move it to the result list, remove a list from the list of lists when it is empty, and iterate until the list of lists itself is empty.

One approach is:

```
def merge(lists):
  result = []

  while len(lists):
    (index, value) = min(enumerate(i[0] for i in lists), key=lambda x: x[1])
    result.append(lists[index].pop(0))
    if len(lists[index]) == 0:
      lists.pop(index)

  return result
```